# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() & pdo_sqlsrv doesn't exist in vscode

Tags: php, sql-server

I try to install Microsoft's driver for PHP.
I have already run the `pecl install sqlsrv-5.10.0` & `pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-5.10.0`,but when I use the phpinfo I didn't see the sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv inside.

I also insert sqlsrv into vscode >> setting >> intelephense >> Stubs,but I didn't see `pdo_sqlsrv` .

Is anyone know slove this problem ? My system is MacOSX